# SELECT one of two Ints and apply conditional formatting

Tags: sql

I have a table [Case] which amongst other fields has two ints, one called [CaseNo] and the other [QueryNo].  Only one of these will exist at any one time, the other will return Null.

I want a SELECT statement that will return [CaseNo] if it exists, and if it doesn't it should return the [QueryNo] proceeded by a 'Q' to denote it is a [QueryNo].

I tried the following statement -

```
SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(50), (ISNULL(CaseNo, 'Q' + QueryNo)))
FROM [Case]
```

But it does not like my Conversion.

Could someone please help me get the right Statement to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CASE` statement:

```
Select Case when caseNo is null then 'Q'+ Convert(varchar(10),queryNo) 
            else Convert(varchar(10),caseNo) end as yourNo
from [Case]
```

Or if you like using isnull/coalesce, you could do:

```
Select isnull(Convert(varchar(10), caseNo),'Q' + Convert(varchar(10), queryNo)) yourNo
from [Case]
```

Comment: But I need to place a 'Q' at the front of the value if it is a QueryNo, so the returned value is going to be a string. For example, if CaseNo is NULL, and QueryNo is 123, I want the Select to return 'Q123'.

Comment: I'd already tried the second suggestion which gives me 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Q' to data type int.'  That is why I was trying to incorporate a conversion to VarChar.